# Show that the function is orthogonal

Tags: orthogonality, sturm-liouville

show directly That the eigenfunction of the given Sturm-Liouville problem are orthogonal without explicitly solving for therm , and state the orthogonality conditions

$x{y}''+{y}'+\lambda xy=0$

${y}'(0)=0$

$y(1)=0$

You can help me with this problem, my doubt is that I want to solve this equation by the Cauchy euler, but ${y}'$ does not have the $x$ to be able to use this method, I do not have any change of variable, I am confused on how to raise this problem , I know, I would appreciate any input regarding this

Comment: Orthogonality is usually with respect to something...

Comment: The question is missing something.

Answer (score 0):

A Sturm-Liouville form of your equation is
$$
                  -(xy')' = \lambda xy
$$

Your problem is singular at $x=0$, which means there is no *a priori* guarantee that solutions will have a finite value or a finite derivative at $x=0$. But, assuming you have two solutions $y_1,y_2$ of the problem that you stated with different corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, then
$$
          (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\int_0^1 xy_1(x)y_2(x) \\
    = \int_0^1 -(xy_1')'y_2+y_1(xy_2')' dx \\
    = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}(-xy_1'y_2+xy_1y_2')dx \\
    = -xy_1'y_2+xy_1y_2'|_0^1 =0.
$$
Because $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$, then $\int_0^1 xy_1(x)y_2(x)dx=0$ must hold. So the two solutions will be orthogonal with respect to the weight function $x$.